# Transport modes/profiles in PTV developer Distance matrix API

Tags: matrix, routes, distance, profile, ptv-developer

I was planning to use PTV Developer API to calculate a distance matrix using something more sophisticated than a Manhattan distance.  However looking at the Routing Matrix API reference I see only references to profiles for vehicles (no bikes, no pedestrians). Does this mean I'm going to get non-optimum routing for pedestrians (e.g. inability to go against a one-way street for vehicles to shorten a route)?  Disappointing if it is the case as I had hoped for a replacement for Google API ...

Answer (score 0):

The PTV Developer API does not offer a pedestrian profile for matrix routing as there must be a precalculated search graph for each profile which contains the distances for all network segments. This would not really make sense in a global context but only in a city. But search graphs can only be precalculated for the complete map and not a single city.
The Routing API does contain the pedestrian profile so maybe you can work around this by using the regular routing API and calculate multiple routes for your matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the PTV Developer API you could look into PTV xServer2 API which offers access to distance matrix computations including parametrizing the profile. Here's a sample request with coordinates in Manhattan - walking direction against the Broadway driving direction (as you wish)

```
{
  "$type": "CreateAndGetDistanceMatrixRequest",
  "storedProfile":"pedestrian",
  "resultFields": {
    "distances": true,
    "travelTimes": true
 },
  "startLocations": [
    {
      "$type": "OffRoadRouteLocation",
      "offRoadCoordinate": {
        "x": -74.006393432617188,
        "y": 40.714599609375
      }
    },
    {
      "$type": "OffRoadRouteLocation",
      "offRoadCoordinate": {
        "x": -74.006607055664062,
        "y": 40.715110778808594
          }
    },
    {
      "$type": "OffRoadRouteLocation",
      "offRoadCoordinate": {
        "x": -74.00543212890625,
        "y": 40.715450286865234
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The response looks like this:

```
{
  "$type": "DistanceMatrixResponse",
  "summary": {
    "numberOfStartLocations": 3,
    "numberOfDestinationLocations": 3,
    "percentageOfDirectDistanceRelations": 0,
    "routingType": "CONVENTIONAL"
  },
  "contents": {
    "$type": "DistanceMatrixContentsArrays",
    "distances": [
      0,
      82,
      168,
      82,
      0,
      194,
      168,
      194,
      0
    ],
    "travelTimes": [
      0,
      77.76,
      141.6,
      77.76,
      0,
      152.16,
      141.6,
      152.16,
      0
    ]
  }
}
```